# Getting "Too much recursion" error in fabric js

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, fabricjs

I am getting "too much recursion" error when I click on object on fabric js

I have added below code in Mouse down event but noting logged in console.

I have used Coffee script.

**Coffee script**

```
@listenTo @canvas, "mouse:up", (o) -> @isDown = false;
@listenTo @canvas, "mouse:down", (o) -> console.log o; @isDown = true;
```

**Compiled Coffee script**

```
this.listenTo(this.canvas, "mouse:up", function(o) {
    return this.isDown = false;
});
this.listenTo(this.canvas, "mouse:down", function(o) {
    console.log(o);
    return this.isDown = true;
});
```

I have not used Clone Method ant where in script.

I have checked same script on my localhost it is working fine. but when i am uploading on server then it is not working.

**Screenshot of Firefox.**

[image]

**Screenshot of Chrome.**

[image]

Comment: can you send a jsfiddle with the problem ?

Comment: I have resolved the issue, It is jQuery issue, I have updated the jQuery and it is working fine.